# How to tell if a key binding will overwrite another

Tags: key-bindings

I configure numerous additional key bindings, and sometimes I unintentionally overwrite others.  Is there a way to determine if a key binding is taken before binding a key, and if so throw an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See function [`lookup-key`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Functions-for-Key-Lookup.html). It will tell you whether a given key is defined in a given map, including in the global map, or even (with non-nil arg `ACCEPT-DEFAULTS`) whether it has a fallback (default) binding in the current context.

For example, if you want to see whether `C-M-kp-+` is defined in the current mode's map:

```el
(lookup-key (current-local-map) (kbd "<C-M-S-kp-add>"))
```

And if you want to see whether it has a global binding:

```el
(lookup-key (current-global-map) (kbd "<C-M-S-kp-add>"))
```

And if you want to see if has a default behavior in the context of the current mode, even though it is not specifically defined:

```el
(lookup-key (current-local-map) (kbd "<C-M-S-kp-add>") t)
```

See also: [Key Lookup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Lookup.html).